# Android Bug or Java Bug : When execute callback find the wrong instance

Tags: java, android

Recently I use `MVP` to develop an Android App.

But I find an Android Bug(maybe I am wrong)

I have two presenter `NewsPresenter` and `MainPresenter`. `NewsPresenter` is created an instance in a Fragment `NewsFragment`,and `MainPresenter` is created an instance in an Activity `MainActivty`.Of course `MainActivity` include `NewsFragment`.Both two presenter have two method to implements which to handle the success response and the fail response.

**NewsPresenter**

```
public class NewsPresenter extends IPresenter implements IAdapter.OnRecycleItemClickListener{
 @Override
 protected void onIRequestSuccess(int requestId, IResponse response) {
    Log.e("TAG","onIRequestSuccess:"+requestId);
    ....
 }

 @Override
 protected void onIRequestFail(int requestId, Throwable throwable) {
    Log.e("TAG","onIRequestFail:"+requestId);
    ...

 }
}
```

**MainPresenter**

```
public class MainPresenter extends IPresenter{

public MainPresenter(Context context, IMain iMain) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onIRequestSuccess(int requestId, IResponse response) {
  //do nothing
}

@Override
protected void onIRequestFail(int requestId, Throwable throwable) {
  //do nothing
}
}
```

Now,in the `NewsPresenter` I try to make a network request.In the `BasePresenter` which is its super class I make a log to show the class which try to execute the network request.And the log is that:

```
01-02 20:09:28.281 17206-17206/com.chengtao.culture E/BasePresenter: class com.chengtao.culture.presenter.NewsPresenter
```

this mean `NewsPresenter` execute the request.

But in the `IPresente` which is `NewsPresenter` and `MainPresenter` super class,I try to make a log to show the class which handle the response.And the log is that:

```
01-02 20:09:38.352 17206-17206/com.chengtao.culture E/TAG: class com.chengtao.culture.presenter.MainPresenter
```

This mains that the `MainPresenter` handle the response.

**IPresenter**

```
abstract class IPresenter extends BasePresenter{
IPresenter(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void onRequestSuccess(int requestId, BaseResponse response) {
    Log.e("TAG",this.getClass().toString());
    IResponse response1 = (IResponse) response;
    Log.e("TAG","onRequestSuccess");
    onIRequestSuccess(requestId,response1);
}
@Override
public void onRequestFail(int requestId, Throwable throwable) {
    Log.e("TAG",this.getClass().toString());
    if (throwable == null || throwable.getMessage() == null){
        throwable = new Throwable("请求超时");
        onIRequestFail(requestId,throwable);
    }else {
        onIRequestFail(requestId,throwable);
    }
}

protected abstract void onIRequestSuccess(int requestId, IResponse response);
protected abstract void onIRequestFail(int requestId, Throwable throwable);

}
```

I am so confused why I use `NewsPresenter` to make the request,but `MainPresenter` handle the response?It's not scientific,because the log show that the request is `NewsPresenter` execute,`MainPresenter` has no relationship with `NewsPresenter` just both of them extends `IPresenter`.

**But once I delete the instance of MainPresenter in the Activity,the response will be handled by the NewsPresenter.**

**To see the whole code:**   https://github.com/ParadiseHell/cultural-creative/tree/master/app/Culture

I make sure my code is all right,So I don't know is `Android bug` or it's `Java bug`.If someone knows,please tell me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I have to say,I use MVP right,just because my [library](https://github.com/ParadiseHell/elegant) has a bug,and I have fixed it.

In the library,there is a class **AsyncHttpClient** which is singleton pattern,of course it's wrong,because I can init only one response interface in the whole project,but every presenter has a response interface,so it's bad for handling the response.So I delete singleton pattern,use a public constructor,and the problem disappears.

**So it's not Android bug or Java bug,just my fault for thinking less.**

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your Mvp architecture is wrong. List and Adapter are related to UI, so adapter logic must be with fragment not with the presenter.

You should create something other called "Service Class" which will extend the BaseService in which the real API call is sent.

Every API call must have each separate Service Class.We should set the callback method to that serviceclass object so that when the API call gets executed the callback is received for that particular function. 
Sample code which explains the above paragraph.

```
class GetNewsService extends BaseService {

void doApiCall(){
// execute API call . Put the request related code in BaseService.
}
}

class NewsPresenter {
 // I am writing psudeo code only.

 void getNews(){
  GetNewsService newsService=new GetNewsService();
  newsService.setCallBack(new RequestClass(){
  @Override
  onSuccessMethod(Response response){
 // send response object to view class through interface and update adapter there
 }

  @Override
  onFailMethod(Error error){}
  });
  newsService.doApiCall();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is right.But I don't think mine is not wrong.Because you don't know how many requests you will have,So I made `IPresenter` to excute all requests and support two abstract methods to handle response.So every presenter just extends `IPresenter` and handle response by the `requestId`. **So I don't need to set callback in every request.**@Sairam Rachapudi

Comment: I just wanna ask how do you explain that when I delete the instance of `MainPresenter` I get right call back in `NewsPresenter`.But when I add,it won't.@Sairam Rachapudi